# Getting value from combobox and send it as a parameter to a method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box in my WinForms and it has values from 1 to 5. I wanted to know how to send the selected combobox value as a parameter to a method.

I am populating my combo box using the below code.

```
public class Form
{
    public Form()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        const int maximumValue = 5;
        for (var i = 1; i <= maximumValue; i++)
        {
            this.comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
        }

        this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 4;
    }
}
```

I wanted to use the above combo box selection as a parameter instead of declaring an `int maxValue = 5` variable to the below function

```
private class Test
{
    private bool Check(int number, int maxValue = 7)
    {
       // Some logic here where I can use comboBox value;
    }

    // Test is an Enum
    public static Test Differentiate(string file1, string file2)
    {
       bool equal = true;
       var number = 1; 

       // Some logic here;

      // currently I am just passing number as a parameter
      equal = Check(number);

      return Test.Ok;
    }
}
```

Also, the `comboBox` code in one class and the method I want to use the `comboBox.SelectedItem` value is in another class. How do I call the `comboBox` code in the class where I want to use it?

Can anyone give me any suggestions as to how to achieve this?

Comment: You can get selected value by using `combobox1.SelectedValue` and convert it to int and pass it to method.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you for the suggestion :) Also, I had another question. I have the `comboBox` code in one class and the method I want to use the `comboBox.SelectedItem`  value is in another class. How do I call the `comboBox` code in the class where I want to use it?

Comment: You don't use combobox in that class. You pass value of combobox to the method as parameter. You need to make the method public instead of private. If you can share more code like from where are you calling check method it will be easier to provide better solution.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have edited my question and provided additional information, can you please have a look? Thank you :)

Comment: You should have one more parameter `maxValue` in `Differentiate` method and pass it to `Test` method too as `equal = Check(number, maxCalue);` why you have one method static and one non-static? How are you calling `Differentiate` in Form?

Comment: Thank you @ChetanRanpariya, I was able to figure out how to do it based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
public object GetComboBoxItem(int index)
{
    if (index >= MyCombo.Items.Count)
        return null;

    return MyCombo.Items[index];
}
```

**Thus, you'll return the value and use it in another subroutine**